# I am very confused about how to solve this system of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

I need to solve a system of 3 equations:

$$
\begin{align}
a + b + c &= 7 \tag{i}\\
9a + 3b + c &= 13 \tag{ii}\\
81a + 9b + c &= 7 \tag{iii}
\end{align}
$$

This is how I solved.

Subtract $(i)$ from $(ii)$:

$
\begin{align}
&& 9a + 3b + c - a - b - c &= 13 - 7\\
\Rightarrow && 8a + 2b &= 6\\
\Rightarrow && 4a + b &= 3\\
\Rightarrow && b &= 4a - 3\tag{iv}
\end{align}
$

Substitute $(iv)$ in $(i)$:

$
\begin{align}
&& a + (4a - 3) + c &= 7\\
\Rightarrow && 5a - 3 + c &= 7\\
\Rightarrow && 5a + c &= 7 + 3\\
\Rightarrow && 5a + c &= 10\\
\Rightarrow && c &= 10 - 5a \tag{v}
\end{align}
$

Substitute $(iv)$ and $(v)$ in $(iii)$:

$
\begin{align}
&& 81a + 9(4a - 3) + (10 - 5a) &= 7\\
\Rightarrow && 81a + 36a - 27 + 10 - 5a &= 7\\
\Rightarrow && 117a - 5a &= 27 + 7 - 10\\
\Rightarrow && 112a &= 24\\
\Rightarrow && a &= \frac{3}{14} \tag{vi}
\end{align}
$

But according to the official solution in the book, the correct value for $a$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest starting with $(i)-(iii)$ as a first step, you get more cancellations immediately.  After that, other things should be more clear.

Comment: Sign is wrong in equation (iv), $b=-4a+3$.

Comment: Would you be allowed to use Gaussian Elimination? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDb6iugi6Uk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation would be more easier ,using your method in another way.

First,(ii)-(i) gives ,
\begin{equation}
\label{iv}
8a+2b  =6
\Rightarrow 4a+b  =3
\end{equation}

(iii)-(i) gives
\begin{equation}
80a+8b=0
\Rightarrow10a+b=0
\end{equation}

Now , Subtract 2nd one from 1st one, $$ -6a=3\Rightarrow a=-1/2$$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to compare with.

The coefficient matrix is the transpose from a Vandermonde's matrix. Precisely, one has:
\begin{align*}
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
9 & 3 & 1\\
81 & 9 & 1
\end{bmatrix} =
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 9 & 81\\
1 & 3 & 9\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = (1 - 9)(1 - 3)(3 - 9) = -96
\end{align*}

According to the Cramer's rule, we need the following determinant:
\begin{align*}
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
7 & 1 & 1\\
13 & 3 & 1\\
7 & 9 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = 21 + 7 + 107 - 21 - 13 - 63 = 48
\end{align*}

as well as the determinant:
\begin{align*}
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 7 & 1\\
9 & 13 & 1\\
81 & 7 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = 13 + 567 + 63 - 1053 - 63 - 7 = -480
\end{align*}
and, finally, the next determinant too:

\begin{align*}
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 7\\
9 & 3 & 13\\
81 & 9 & 7
\end{bmatrix} = 21 + 1053 + 567 - 1701 - 63 - 117 = -240
\end{align*}

Consequently, the solution set is given by the triple:
\begin{align*}
\left(a,b,c\right) = \left(-\frac{48}{96},\frac{480}{96},\frac{240}{96}\right) = \left(-\frac{1}{2},5,\frac{5}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: The question asks for an explanation of what was done wrong in the approach taken. All the steps are there, and some of the comments are quite on target in stating incorrect steps. This answer addresses none of that, but only applies Kramer's rule on the system.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, indeed. I have edited my answer to stress out it is also another possibility.

Comment: This is actually interesting, didn't know about Vandermonde's matrix.